# Access Violation continuously thrown by _findnext (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am incredibly unfamiliar with c/c++ but have found myself needing to compile a fairy large project from source (obviously not my code). I have managed to work through many of the small issues over the past few days, but I can't quite work out this one.

There is a class MP_DLL_Manager_c with a method search_library that consistently produces access violation errors. Unfortunately it is called by every single application the source compiles as it is required in order to set up the environment.

the method is:

```
bool MP_Dll_Manager_c::search_library(vector<string> * lib_names, const char * path)
{
  struct _finddata_t c_file;
  long hFile;
  static string fname;
  string buffer;
  buffer = path;
  buffer  += "\\";
  buffer += MP_Dll_Manager_c::get_dll_type();
  if ( (hFile = (long)_findfirst(buffer.c_str(), &c_file)) == -1L )
    {
      mp_error_msg( "MP_Dll_Manager::search_library","No *.dll files in current directory: [%s]\n", buffer.c_str() );
      return false;
    }
  else
    { if (strcmp( c_file.name ,"mptk.dll") && strcmp( c_file.name ,"libmptk.dll") && strcmp( c_file.name ,"mptk4matlab.dll") && strcmp( c_file.name ,"libmptk4matlab.dll") ){
      fname = path ;
      fname += "\\";
      fname += c_file.name;


      (*lib_names).push_back(fname);
    }

      while (_findnext(hFile, &c_file) == 0 )
        {
        if (strcmp( c_file.name ,"mptk.dll") && strcmp( c_file.name ,"libmptk.dll") && strcmp( c_file.name ,"mptk4matlab.dll") && strcmp( c_file.name ,"libmptk4matlab.dll") ){
          fname = path ;
          fname += "\\";
          fname += c_file.name;
          (*lib_names).push_back(fname);}

        }
      _findclose(hFile);
    }

  return true;
}
```

It's just supposed to return the dlls in the specified path (provided they don't match any that shouldn't be there). However, I'm getting an unhandled exception at _findnext - an access violation. I can't figure out the cause.

[call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJVf6.png)

Answer (score 5):

Use `intptr_t hFile` instead of long in defining the name of the file. You can refer to MSDN documentation [_findnext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkkkc1y.aspx)

Comment: I could have sworn I'd tried that, but apparently I didn't! Thanks for your help - it seems to have solved the problem. I'm not sure why the original developers used a long and casted the output of _findfirst but given my lack of familiarity with the language I just assumed there was a reason.